# Getting data out of a inner class

Tags: java, arraylist, parse-platform, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I've been getting really frustrated with an issue. How do I access the data that I get in a inner class. I'm using Parse for the back end of my new application but all parse methods are used anonymously and are inner classes so I can't really access anything that is retrieved. Is there a way around it?

I tried this and it didn't work. Everything needs to be final and finals can not be altered within the inner class.

Here's my code.

```
 imageView_intro = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_intro);
    List<Bitmap> list = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
   BackEndUtils.downloadIntroImage(list);
    imageView_intro.setImageBitmap(list.get(0));
```

```
public static void  downloadIntroImage(final List<Bitmap> list){
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Intro");
    query.whereEqualTo("name","intro");

    //BEUFindCallBack beuFindCallBack = new BEUFindCallBack("image");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject> (){

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            for(ParseObject tempObject: parseObjects){
                ParseFile tempFile = (ParseFile)tempObject.get("image");
                tempFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(byte[] bytes, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        list.add(bytesToBitMap(bytes));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

public static Bitmap bytesToBitMap(byte[] bytes){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                            .decodeByteArray(
                                    bytes, 0,
                                    bytes.length);
    return bitmap;
}
```

At the end, the list still has a size of 0... meaning nothing was actually added to it. How can I access the `byte[]` variable and pull out of the inner class!?

The weird thing is, if I send the image view and set the bitmapimage there inside the inner class it works. But I want to be able to take the byte array out of the inner anonymous class and save it somewhere so I can work on it later.

Comment: When you say `inner class`, are you referring to the `anonymous class` inside the `done` method?

Comment: Presumably, the `tempFile.getDataInBackground` will start a thread and do the work in the background. You won't see the result until "later". If you need the result "now", don't do the work to the background.

Comment: @Andreas no i just need to be able access the result that is sent in the done method. I don't care when it's done. I just need to access it and save it into a variable , return it or save it somewhere.

Comment: I know exactly what you are going through. The pain of only final variables being accessible inside anonymous blocks and them not being modifiable.  Faced the same while using Smart GWT. Tell you what class level variables are accessible inside these blocks even if they are non-final and they get updated correctly.
You may want to make sure that the block gets executed though because the callbacks tend to be asynchronous many a times giving an impression that values are not getting updated.

Comment: @digidude The problem has nothing to do with `final`. The parameter `list` cannot be reassigned, but the list it references can be updated, no problem.

Comment: @digidude Can you elaborate on that one? The block does get executed because if I send an ImageView to downloadintroimage and then do. view.setimagebitmap from within the anonymous inner class, then it works! so the the method does get called.!

Comment: @OmerOzer well the block certainly gets executed but at the instance when you are actually checking for the size of list in which you are adding bytes, the method should have already executed. 
So if you simply go ahead and check the list size right after the anonymous block in code, you might still see the list size as 0 as the callback method has not yet executed. The blocks are usually asynchronous and won't halt the program for them to return values.

Comment: @OmerOzer In similar cases I usually hault further execution using some clickable buttons and retrieve values on button clicks to allow for the aynchronous method to execute completely. I am not sure how feasible it is in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `com.parse.ParseFile`, then use `getData()` to wait for the data. Don't use `getDataInBackground()`.

Same for `ParseQuery`, use `find()`.

Your problem is that `BackEndUtils.downloadIntroImage(list)` returns before the data has been retrieved, so `imageView_intro.setImageBitmap(list.get(0))` will see an empty list.

Comment: I think I see what youre saying. I'm going to try that now!

Comment: It worked. I love you :D I'm just going to run it on my own background thread.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone experiencing this or any other similar problems, this specific case was caused by a background thread not completing on time and therefor not returning values as intented. That's why it worked to use getData instead of getDataInBackground.